# how to check key available or not in json response in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, json

After i request to the server , i recieve two different type of response

if it is success response will be this

```
[{"id":5,"is_default":0,"name":"Dutch","language_id":3},{"id":4,"is_default":1,"name":"French","language_id":2}]
```

other response type would be

```
 {"status":102,"response":"Empty record list."}
```

Is the any way to detect whether the "status" key is available or not in response in objc.
Thanks

found a solution

```
   //break it from result tag    
if([[responseString JSONValue] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

    NSDictionary *dict = [responseString JSONFragmentValue];

    if([dict count]==2){
      return;
    }
    //nothing to load

}
```

Comment: `if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) ...` then you have the latter, a response with dictionary with `status`. `if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) ...` then you have the former, the array of dictionary entries.

Answer (score 2):

`Parse` the `JSON` response into `object`. Check if parsed `object` is `dictionary`, then check the key `"status"`.

If the parsed `object` is an `array`, then access the `results` from `index`.

Answer (score 2):

The response is just a dictionary, so to see if you have the key you are looking for you can just use the NSDictionary methods:

```
// Assume you have already created a dictionary, jsonResponse, from your JSON

// First, get all the keys in the response

NSArray *responseKeys = [jsonResponse allKeys];

// Now see if the array contains the key you are looking for

BOOL isErrorResponse = [responseKeys containsObject:@"status"];
```

Comment: i have already tried . but if i recieve this response [{"id":5,"is_default":0,"name":"Dutch","language_id":3},{"id":4,"is_default":1,"name":"French","language_id":2}]

app will crash

Comment: Then your response is an array, You can either assume that if you have an array then you don't have an error response, or you could apply this test to each dictionary in the array.

Comment: android api does have a solution for this, im wondering y the apple hasn't implemented a solution fot it

Comment: assume if i recieve {"id":5,"is_default":0,"name":"Dutch","language_id":3}

not multiple elements

Comment: Really? What bit of my answer doesn't apply in that case?

Comment: If thr is no record the response will be this 
{"status":102,"response":"Empty record list."}

Also imagine if thrs only one element availble for the response
then the response will be this
{"id":5,"is_default":0,"name":"Dutch","language_id":3} 
so from these two response how can i identify two of them separately

Comment: @Mr.G - which Android API are you referring too? There are three different ones.